# Issue with JQuery wrap method on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm a little new to JQuery but I seem to be running into a challenge with cross-browser functionality. I have the following code inserted at the head of the form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  /*wraps the action field in the Completed div with link to section*/
  $('input[id^="tfa_5660"]').val(function(i,origText) {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + origText + '">Review this section</a>');
    return "";
  });

  /*wraps the action field in the To-Do div with link to section*/
  $('input[id^="tfa_5714"]').val(function(i,origText) {
     $(this).wrap('<a href="' + origText + '">Start this section</a>');
     return "";
  }); 

});
</script>
```

The jQuery function works on Chrome and Safari, but when I test it on Firefox, rather than wrapping it with the link from the input value it wraps the input with the url of the page itself. Any idea what might be causing the issues with Firefox but not Chrome or Safari?

See below for screenshots demonstrating the issue

Firefox: 
[Screenshot of Firefox not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE516.png)

Below is the HTML of the form itself, generated by a WYSIWYG form editor called Form Assembly

```
<div class="htmlSection" id="tfa_5655"><div class="htmlContent" id="tfa_5655-HTML">Below is a list of the sections you've already completed.</div></div>
<table class="gridLayout ">
<thead><tr class="headerRow">
<th scope="col" id="tfa_5657[0]-GRID" class="">Section  </th>
<th scope="col" id="tfa_5658[0]-GRID" class=""><b>Description</b>       </th>
<th scope="col" id="tfa_5659[0]-GRID" class=""><b>Due Date</b>     </th>
<th scope="col" id="tfa_5660[0]-GRID" class=""><b>Action </b> </th>
<th scope="col" id="tfa_5661[0]-GRID" class=" wf-acl-hidden">Click here to name this section  </th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="tfa_5656[0]" class="section repeat   alternate-0 " data-repeatlabel=" ">
<td class=""><div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5657-D[0]"><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_5657[0]" name="tfa_5657[0]" value="Contact Information" placeholder="" default="Contact Information" readonly title="Section " class="readonly"></div></div></td>
<td class=""><div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5658-D[0]"><div class="inputWrapper"><textarea id="tfa_5658[0]" name="tfa_5658[0]" readonly title="Description " class="readonly">Tell us about yourself</textarea></div></div></td>
<td class=""><div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5659-D[0]"><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_5659[0]" name="tfa_5659[0]" value="" placeholder="" readonly title="Due Date " class="readonly"></div></div></td>
<td class=""><div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5660-D[0]"><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_5660[0]" name="tfa_5660[0]" value="" placeholder="" readonly title="Action " class="formula=LinkReview+IDReview readonly"></div></div></td>
<td class=" wf-acl-hidden"><fieldset id="tfa_5661[0]" class="section wf-acl-hidden">
<legend id="tfa_5661[0]-L">Click here to name this section </legend>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5662-D[0]">
<label id="tfa_5662[0]-L" for="tfa_5662[0]" class="label preField "><b>ID</b>    </label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_5662[0]" name="tfa_5662[0]" value="00To000001mtE3aEAE" placeholder="" default="00To000001mtE3aEAE" readonly title="ID " class="calc-IDReview readonly"></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     " id="tfa_5663-D[0]">
<label id="tfa_5663[0]-L" for="tfa_5663[0]" class="label preField "><b>Link</b>     </label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_5663[0]" name="tfa_5663[0]" value="https://www.tfaforms.com/4605490?what_id=" placeholder="" default="https://www.tfaforms.com/4605490?what_id=" readonly title="Link " class="calc-LinkReview readonly"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the form itself, realized I probably should have included this from the start: https://www.tfaforms.com/4605382?contact_id=003o000000v6WOF

Comment: jQuery is inherently cross browser - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: by the way, your code produces exactly the same results for me in firefox and chrome - of course, without seeing all your HTML, can only guess that the HTML I created to check your code is at all relevant - perhaps your firefox has some old code cached or something

Comment: Just ran your code in both browser, it works. Are you running a super early version of FireFox?

Comment: well, your code doesn't behave differently in firefox - perhaps there's something in the code (JS, HTML and/or CSS) you haven't shown that actually causes the issue you are seeing

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I actually just downloaded so I'm running Firefox 54, which I'm pretty sure is the latest version.

I can edit the post to include the HTML, its actually generated by a WYSIWYG form editor called Form Assembly

Comment: I just updated the original post with the html of the form that the JQuery is referencing